# How to send data using ajax and display different values?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Firstly, I like to say sorry if I cannot explain the question properly.

**Here I have a js code:**

```
$('#myHref').change(function(){
    var value = $('#myHref').val();
    $.get('get_projectName.php',{id:value},function(data){
        $('#projectDetail').html(data);
    }); 
});
```

Let, `get_projectName.php` contain `$a=5; $b=10; $c=15;`

**I want to display:**

- `$a=5` as value of S.N. inputfield
- `$b=10` as value of Detail inputfield
- `$c=15` as value of Sector inputfield.

[image]

`<input type="text" value="value of $a here">`
`<input type="text" value="value of $b here">`
`<input type="text" value="value of $c here">`

Comment: Negative marking or downvote is much easier then answering, instead of doing this down vote plz ask the question where u dnt understand or where I don't clear properly

Comment: show the fragment of your html containing  inputs -  i think its a table or divs

Comment: set some class to your input boxes and set the value what is come from the ajax call through data.

Comment: If you have to design entire `source of information` in the `get_projectName.php` then its batter, just return the total HTML from that page.

Comment: You seem to be asking for an introductory guide to outputting variables into HTML with PHP (and possible also a basic "how to write a form in HTML" guide). The JavaScript isn't really relevant to the problem. That's really something you should be learning from an introductory tutorial.

Comment: @DharaParmar Did u down vote? I thnk u did. myHref is id clearly u can see bcoz there is #myHref. This id of `source of information` dropdown in top of image. Next thing is that it is not important what is #myHref and where it came from

Comment: I think you should explain little more regarding your problem. As much as i can understand, the problem with you is to display the values to a,b,c.

Comment: In you ajax call you will get response. So this response depends on you Server. So advice is in your response you will send your data and bind that data in you HTML.

Comment: @yank -- hey I  have not downvoted your post...

Comment: @FrayneKonok how to set 3 different values and show in 3 different places. And `source of information` cnt be designed in `get_projectName.php` bcoz I have to show `$a,$b,$c` if `source of information` is selected

Comment: "get_projectName.php" In which format its giving response?

Comment: @RoliAgrawal get is the method, I dont understand u tried to ask abt format

Comment: @DharaParmar, thanks nyway. I have few reputation and I nearly blocked to ask question due to negative or down vote, so I was little concern abt it. May be 1 or 2 down votes will block me asking question. So I need some upvote

Answer (score 0):

To set a value of an `<input>` in jQuery:

```
$( 'input' ).val("Enter value here");
```

If you're wondering how to give data back to the AJAX function from PHP, just `echo` the response. It will be the value of `data` in your `.get` success callback. You'll probably need to JSON-encode the data:

In your PHP, put this at the end, after you have $a, $b and $c (and do not `echo`/output anything before this line):

```
die(json_encode(array(
    'a' => $a,
    'b' => $b,
    'c' => $c
)));
```

You will receive JSON in your JS. Parse it to get the values, and then set the `<input>` values to them:

```
$.get('get_projectName.php', {
  id: value
}, function(data) {
  data = JSON.parse(data);
  $( '#inputA' ).val(data.a);
  $( '#inputB' ).val(data.b);
  $( '#inputC' ).val(data.c);
});
```

Comment: @yank I have done it for this, but please learn the concepts afterwards -- it's not that hard, Google is your friend :)

Comment: Thnks for code. I will learn from ur code n learn from google in detail. really appreciated. I hope it also help a lot for other beginner too.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add an id to these input fields?

```
<input id="sn" type="text">
<input id="detail" type="text">
<input id="sector" type="text">

$('#myHref').change(function(){
    var value = $('#myHref').val();
    $.get('get_projectName.php',{id:value},function(data){
        $('#projectDetail').html(data);
        $('#sn').val(data.a);
        $('#detail').val(data.b);
        $('#sector').val(data.c);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: How `$('#sn').val(data.a);` will hold the value of `$a` ? specially `data.a` does` n how it is related to `$a`

Comment: HI @yank, this was an example, I don't know you are retrieving this data. If you show me what is in this data, I can do a more accurate example.